# Implementing MVC and Observer Pattern

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

For a group project for school we have to make a program that implements the MVC pattern.

The difficulty I have is understanding how the MVC pattern is implemente in java with SWING, does the view make the SWING components?

Another thing I have a hard time understanding is what updates what. For instance one article says the view 'executes' the controller, then the controller updates the model accordingly, the model the notifies the view and and the view then pulls the data from the model.

While what i've learned about the MVC Pattern is that the controller has an instance of the model and the view so it can interact with both. but then if I push a button in the view how does the controller know to do something with the model? And for this example which clas(ses) is/are the Observer(s) and which clas(ses) are the Observable(s)?

Another idea I had is that if we use the MVC Pattern as described above the view is the Observer and the model is the Observable, but that still leaves the question how does the controller know when to update the model?

If it seems vague please ask for clarification in the comments and I will answer.

Comment: Please can you format your question so its readable?

Comment: @almasshaikh better?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on what your exact question is. At the moment the question is too broad. Can you narrow it down a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View communicates with the controller, the controller communicates with the model and vice-versa.

Say you have a model class `Graph` that contains the points of a graph. Your views purpose is to display that graph. The `Graph` class would be an [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) that **the controller** observes. If the controller observes change, it will tell the view update/change accordingly. If you press a button on the view, say to display a different graph object, your button has an [`actionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) that asks the controller to change the graph.

And yes, your view classes would create the Swing components.

Comment: So in the `actionListener`i have an instance of the `controller`, but the controller needs an instance of the view so it can update the view, how do i program that?

Comment: The view is created (and probably saved in a field) by the controller.

Comment: But how do I interact with the controller from the view?

Comment: You can pass the controller as an argument when calling the view's constructor `View myView = new View(this)` inside the controller. Then the view can methods on the controller object. If you want to make something happen at the press of a button, please check out the `actionListener` page I linked in the original answer.